# MVC bootstrap carousel firefox issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm using bootstrap carousel, and it works fine in chrome and explorer, but for some reason in firefox 35.0.1, when the image loads it only loads half of the image than the rest takes longer to load.   Anyone have a problem with this in firefox? I'm surprised firefox is the problem here, since it is usually IE that I have issue with.  The problem just started with this new version of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You are not the only one. We've seen this across multiple Windows boxes with FF 35.0.1. We've not tried this on a Mac, though. Can confirm this problem exists, and am really glad we're not the only ones who've noticed it. It's a consistent issue, regardless of caching or network speed.

Great news!: It's been fixed in Firefox 36! Try updating your browser. Here's the Bugzilla which should have addressed the problem: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1125077